# flask, pymongo, forms - loading pymongo data into a form for editing

Tags: python, flask, pymongo, wtforms, flask-wtforms

*What I am trying to achieve:*

I am trying to build a very simple admin interface from scratch that stores text fields and images in a mongodb. The user can then login and make small changes to the content of the site.

*My issue and where I think I am confused:*

Is it possible in pymongo to generate forms with the existing db records showing (so they can be edited and updated in the db)? After trying to understand the problem, I think my confusion lies whether or not I can use WTForms with pymongo directly or if I need to use object based mappers, such as MongoEngine.

Here is my flask app:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
# define the mongo connection
app.config['DB_HOST'] = 'mongodb://localhost/'
app.config['DB_PORT'] = 27017
app.config['DB_DBNAME'] = 'my_db'
the_db = PyMongo(app, config_prefix='DB')

#others routes here...

@app.route("/admin/")
def dashboard():
    pages = list(the_db.db.pages.find({}))
    return render_template('admin.html', pages=pages)

@app.route('/admin/update', methods=['POST'])
def update():
    updated = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    page = request.form['page_name']
    header = request.form['header']
    body = request.form['body']

    h_db.db.pages.update_one(
        {'page': page},
        {'$set':
            {
                'updated': updated,
                'header': header,
                'body': body
            }
        }, upsert=True)

    pages = list(the_db({}))
    return render_template('admin.html', pages=pages)
```

Here is the template:

```
{% for i in pages %}
    {{ i.page }}<br>
{% endfor %}


{% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
<form action="/admin/update" autocomplete="on" method="POST">
    {{ render_field(form.username) }}
    <input type="text" name="page_name" /><br/>
    <input type="text" name="header" /><br/>
    <input type="TextAreaField" name="body" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" /><br/>
</form>
```

Comment: This is one example where I've chosen Django over Flask. The admin is already included and also includes an editing view. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually really simple.  If you look at the HTML docs for forms then you'll find you can do something like:

```
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey"><br>
```

And "Mickey" will show up in the form for you.  So, with flask all you need to do is declare variables in the server code that holds values from your mongodb call for the route and then pass them to the template like you do with "pages"  Then in the front end you can render this dynamically with embedded python in Jinja, something like:

```
@app.route("/admin/<int:page>")
def dashboard(page):
    pages = the_db.db.pages.find({page})
    for p in pages:
        page_name = [p['page']]
        header = [p['header']]
        body = [p['body']]
    return render_template('admin.html', page_name=page_name, header=header, body=body)
```

Then you can take your template and embed like:

```
<form action="/admin/update" autocomplete="on" method="POST">
    {{ render_field(form.username) }}
    <input type="text" name="page_name" value={{ page_name|string }}/><br/>
    <input type="text" name="header" value={{ header|string }}/><br/>
    <input type="TextAreaField" name="body" value={{ body|string }}/><br/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" /><br/>
</form>
```

I'm not a WTForms expert, so I'm probably bypassing some helpers that it offers, but for the most part the basics are here.  Summarizing:

You need to parse the elements of the MongoDB document and pass them to the template.  You can use Jinja's power of dynamically rendering these values to the front-end IN THE APPROPRIATE PLACE as outlined by the HTML standard (the "values" placeholder in the  elements).  This will get you what you want at it's most basic.

If you want to get fancy you can look at AngularJS to handle the front-end MVC and you can visualize your edits on the fly before submission...sort of like what you see here on SO.com where your post shows up live beneath the edit box.

Comment: now you have explained, it does seem kind of simple. one more thing, should the @app.route('/admin/update' be updated to include a page id as well?

Comment: That's sort of up to you.  I also sort of assumed that the /admin/<int:page> request is coming from a UI template that passes the page id to it.  For the /update you could certainly have page id as part of the output to the admin.html template and then the submit would send it through with your update request.  That would be really elegant.